# How to convert the array to a vector in R?

Tags: arrays, r, class

I have a variable with 11 element. I want to define it as array but whatever I do, its class always is "character".

```
> WI[1,]
 [1] ""                                                        
 [2] ""                                                        
 [3] ""                                                        
 [4] ""                                                        
 [5] ""                                                        
 [6] ""                                                        
 [7] "idea rejected ( first reviewer ) "                       
 [8] "rejected ,    team    token   reward  recognition scheme"
 [9] "idea/0000/0000"                                                                                                  
> foo=WI[1,]

> dim(foo)
NULL
> length(foo)
[1] 9
> class(foo)
[1] "character"
> class(as.vector(foo))
[1] "character"

> as.vector(foo)
 [1] ""                                                        
 [2] ""                                                        
 [3] ""                                                        
 [4] ""                                                        
 [5] ""                                                        
 [6] ""                                                        
 [7] "idea rejected ( first reviewer ) "                       
 [8] "rejected ,    team    token   reward  recognition scheme"
 [9] "idea/0000/0000"
```

I tried a lot of different ways and all of them has failed.
What can I do, how can I convert them into an array or a single column. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you're confused about what the basic data types in R are. Do you mean a one column matrix, i.e. something with two dimensions, rows and columns?

Comment: The R FAQ about basic data types might be of use to you: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects

Comment: @joran  Since `> dim(foo)
NULL` , I think foo is not a matrix. (actually "foo" is a row I extract from a matrix)

Comment: @joran Please check the code again, I've add some information on it.

Comment: I was not suggesting that `foo` was a matrix; it is quite obviously a vector (1-d). I was trying to clarify what you're looking for since you are not using your terminology in a very clear manner. You "answer" below, for instance results in a data frame, which is neither an array nor a matrix, and yet that is what your question claims to ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it as an array, use array()

```
contents = sample(c("", "saf", "fsf"), 10, replace = T)
array(contents)
```

If you want to make it as matrix, then

```
matrix(contents, ncol = 1)
```

Comment: Since the OP is _already_ confused about data types in R, you should probably make it clear that the only difference between a matrix and an array in R is that a matrix always has 2 dimensions, while an array can have 1, 2 or more dimensions. Most people don't actually use `array` when they are only interested in something with two dimensions (as a convention).

Comment: @joran Thank you for pointing out my confusion. My problem is the same with this [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Converting-1-D-array-to-vector-td864721.html) but I can not find any solution from there. I tried everything I can. Could you tell me how to convert an array to a vector? Thank you so much!

Answer (score -4):

I found the solution now. Though it is awkward, it does work. I hope someone can provoke some better answer with much easier way.

```
> as.data.frame(t(foo),stringsAsFactors=F)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6                                V7
1                   idea rejected ( first reviewer ) 
                                                        V8             V9 
1 rejected ,    team    token   reward  recognition scheme idea/0000/0000        
> dim(as.data.frame(t(foo),stringsAsFactors=F))
[1]  1 9
> dim(unlist(as.data.frame(t(foo),stringsAsFactors=F)))
NULL
> length(unlist(as.data.frame(t(foo),stringsAsFactors=F)))
[1] 9
```